# Regular expression cant be extended to find similar pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

i am trying to match a pattern of ( dd/yy - dd/yy ) or (0d/yyyy - 0d/yyyy). Any possible combinations of the similar pattern in the text.

My text is:

```
 text  = ''' 09/14 - 18/18 some text 09/13 – 04/14 '''
```

My pattern is:

```
 r"b([\d]{1,2}[\s/-]+[\d]{2,4}[-:\s.]+\d{1,2}[\s/-]+[\d]{2,4}[\s/-]+)"
```

It successfully matches 09/14 - 18/18 . But not matching  09/13 – 04/14 in the text. 
Another doubt I am having is , if I want to check if say "09/14 - " is followed by a "word (any word in a list)" or a pattern like "dd/yy or dd/yyyy" what should I do. My point is if it matches any of the either check I have to pick that with "09/14". ie, "09/14 - word" if it matches or "09/14 - dd/yyyy" if it matches .

Comment: where the starting `b` comes from?

Comment: b is used for boundary checkin @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It successfully matches 09/14 - 18/18 . But not matching 09/13 – 04/14 in the text.

Because `-` and `–` are different characters.

```
\b([\d]{1,2}[\s/-]+[\d]{2,4}[-:–\s.]+\d{1,2}[\s/-]+[\d]{2,4}[\s/-]+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zB3uD4/3)

Use this if you don't want to capture the spaces following the match.

```
\b([\d]{1,2}[\s/-]+[\d]{2,4}[-:–\s.]+\d{1,2}[\s/-]+[\d]{2,4})\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zB3uD4/4)

> if I want to check if say "09/14 - " is followed by a "word (any word in a list)" or a pattern like "dd/yy or dd/yyyy" what should I do.

```
\b[\d]{1,2}[\s/-]+[\d]{2,4}[-:–\s.]+(?:\d{1,2}[\s/-]+[\d]{2,4}|\w)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zB3uD4/5)

```
>>> text  = ''' 09/14 - 18/18 some text 09/13 – 04/14 '''
>>> re.findall(r'\b([\d]{1,2}[\s/-]+[\d]{2,4}[-:–\s.]+\d{1,2}[\s/-]+[\d]{2,4})\b', text)
['09/14 - 18/18', '09/13 – 04/14']
```

Comment: @ Avinash Raj - Can you pls tell the difference between  - and – ?

Comment: how i tell the difference between those. See the first hyphen is smaller than the second one. So it's different.

Comment: haha ...Thanks man. Will check your answer. give me some time .